# Remote Desktop Manager maximized view extends beyond the bottom of the screen - how to fix it?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, rdc-manager

I use RDCMan v2.7 build 1406.0. It annoys me profoundly that on my laptop I just cannot make it show the window right.

I have a chrome page with a Save button at the bottom:
[image]

The RDCMan is currently mazimized, but not full screen. Now I maximize the chrome window:
[image]

Now I switch RDCMan to full screen:
[image]

Notice the vertical scrollbar, indicating that the full screen of RDCMan occupies more space than my laptop's screen resolution. It drives me mad that I cannot adjust it.

Here is the relevant properties window:
[image]

How can we fix the damn thing?

Let me be clear - I want RDCMan full screen mode to fit the laptop screen, how can this be done?

Comment: I usually grab the top bar, drag it down a bit. Then grab the very top (turns into an arrow) and make the window shorter so if fits. Make sure the whole thing fits and then the app should remember its size when closed and re-launched.

Comment: I added a clarification - I want RDCMan to fit the laptop screen in full screen mode, I do not want to resize the windows manually.

Comment: Full screen mode for some tools does not work very well. See if you can make the Window fit as I described. You can drag it nearly full screen manually once it fits. Then the app should remember. Try it to see.

Comment: The problem with remember is that I periodically connect my other monitor, drag the RDCMan to it and there the window sizes change. The problem is specifically when it is on my laptop screen.